# Relative risk from logistics regression in R

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, relative-risk

I can't seem to find a way to get relative risk (instead of odds ratio) in R via glm() function. However, the equivalence seems to be glm() with poisson family and log link, which I suspect will yield the relative risk (or relative proportion, depending on the problem) when the coefficients are exponentiated. Is this correct?

For example, let's say that:

- y is a binary variable (1/0)
- x1 is a continuous variable
- x2 is a binary variable
- x3 is a binary variable

y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 with glm() with family=poisson(link="log") yielded the following coefficients:

- (intercept)=-2.08
- x1         =-0.02
- x2         =-0.004
- x3         =0.25

And then when the coefficients get exponentiated:

- (intercept)=0.12
- x1         =0.98
- x2         =1
- x3         =1.29

Does the exponentiated coefficients means:

1. Relative proportion of y increases by 0.98 times (or decreases by 2%) for every one unit increase of x1?
2. Relative proportion of y is unchanged regardless of the choice in x2
3. Relative proportion of y increases by 1.29 times (or increases by 29%) when x3=1 compared to x3=0?

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of the exponentiated coefficient from a Poisson regression as a relative risk depends on how data were collected.

[This paper by GY Zou](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15033648/) is a very well known paper for showing that Poisson regression + robust covariance estimation yields estimates of relative risk + good coverage of the resulting confidence interval.  The thing to note here is that there is a caveat on the sampling design:  the data must be from a prospective study.

The procedure would NOT produce valid estimates of the relative risk in, say, a case control design because the frequency of cases may not reflect the true frequency in the population.